# How to achieve same IP reservation with WiFi Range Extender

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp, wireless-extender

I am trying to understand how WiFi Range extenders work at setup level. 
I am going thru the specifications and user manuals available on manufacturer websites and it’s adding to my confusion.

I have DHCP IP reservation (against MAC ID) setup in my DIR 615 main router and you can not repeat IP address.

Now I understand that extender translates client’s MAC ID to a Virtual MAC that host router shall see. I want to seamlessly carry say my laptop anywhere in the house with IP reservation & MAC filtering on. I can add both MAC ids to the list but I can not have same IP for two MAC ids. In that case do I need to maintain two IPs under DHCP reservation?

When a client is equidistant from both Router & Extender where will it connect to?

Should  DHCP on Extender be turned off and let Router do all the IP Assignment?

Thanks.